# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying log to AWS cloud watch and I am getting this error. same code was working all from yesterday without issues.
I looked into some article and I installed certifi package as well but this also did not help

I am using Python 3.5 and watchtower to log data to AWS cloud watch.
I am running my python code in windows 10 OS.

Can you please help me with this?

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked,
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
> ssl_context=context,
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
> return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
> _context=self)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 747, in **init**
> self.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 263, in send
> chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
> method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 379, in increment
> raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked,
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
> self.*validate_conn(conn)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
> ssl_context=context,
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
> return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
> *context=self)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 747, in **init**
> self.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
> self.*sslobj.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
> self.*sslobj.do_handshake()
> urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (*ssl.c:646)
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File ".\test_main.py", line 2, in 
> import test_provision_api
> File "C:\Users\BBB\Documents\Drive D\GIT_Local\NBNBNN\Python_Logging\V2.1\test_provision_api.py", line 39, in 
> obj_PdAdmin.call_provisionadmin(pv_url1, WssVersion_list[0], master_AffId[0], master_Culture[0])
> File "C:\Users\BBB\Documents\Drive D\GIT_Local\NBNBNN\Python_Logging\V2.1\test_provision_api.py", line 26, in call_provisionadmin
> HttpJsonlogger.info('PD Admin - /ProductDefinition', extra=pd_admin_extra)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1279, in info
> self.*log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1415, in *log
> self.handle(record)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1425, in handle
> self.callHandlers(record)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1487, in callHandlers
> hdlr.handle(record)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 855, in handle
> self.emit(record)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\watchtower_*init**.py", line 174, in emit
> logStreamName=stream_name)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\watchtower_*init**.py", line 20, in _idempotent_create
> _callable(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 316, in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
> operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 641, in _make_request
> return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
> return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
> success_response, exception):
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
> caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 356, in emit
> return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
> return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
> response = handler(**kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 183, in **call**
> if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 251, in **call**
> caught_exception)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
> return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 317, in **call**
> caught_exception)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 223, in **call**
> attempt_number, caught_exception)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
> raise caught_exception
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
> http_response = self._send(request)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
> return self.http_session.send(request)
> File "C:\Users\BBB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 281, in send
> raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
> botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://logs.**-****-*.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific about your case but certificate validation always end up with the following solutions:

- the certificate is expired
- the certificate is not trusted because you don't have the public key or the certificate authority in your trust file/truststore
- the domain is not covered by the certificate

The message provided seems to tell the domain https://logs.-**-.amazonaws.com is not covered by the certificate

So download the certificate, get the details and check if:

- "Delivered to" field cover the domain name
- one of "Subject Alternative Name (SAN)" cover the domain name

EDIT:

To download the certificate either use a browser to load the url and use the "lock" icon to download the certificate or use openssl utility to download the certificate from the url. To get the details, save the certificate with the ".cer" extension and double click on it or use openssl utility to get the details from a certificate file.

Good luck

Comment: i followed these steps  and installed the certificate to local and current user but no luck, i am getting the same issue again

Comment: I'm guessing python do not use the system certificates. So check how to configure trusted certificates for python. But maybe you're using the aws python client boto so check how to configure it. Can you provide more details about the library you're using?

Comment: sure, i have below setting in YAML file
WatchTowerHandler:
    (): watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler
    formatter: jsonformat
    filters: [FilterEmailID, GetProductdata, GetCustomAttributes]
    level: DEBUG
    log_group: group-test
    stream_name: stream-test
    send_interval: 1
    create_log_group: false
    use_queues: True
    max_batch_size: 1048576
    #1048576 is the max_batch_size
    max_batch_count: 10000
    #10000 is max_batch_count
    boto3_profile_name: default

Comment: Maybe update your question and provide a bit of code. The one generating the exception would be a good starting point

Comment: Sure Mumrah. i will add more details here. Thank you for your prompt reply